# Is there a way to query for stat values in the same solr query request?

Tags: solr, facet

I would like to be able to use term facets to bucket and generate stats, like average cost per country, but also be able to specify a query clause on that average.

In sql terms it would be 
`SELECT country, avg(cost) GROUP BY country HAVING cost > 150`

The challenge here is how to define the query criteria ( > 150) on the stat function of avg(cost).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find a solution using 5.x, I looked to the `SQL RequestHandler` in version 6.0.  This required me to upgrade to 6.0 as well as run in `Cloud` mode.

This example request solved my issue:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/MyCore/sql?wt=json&stmt=select country, avg(cost) from MyCore where region = 'east' group by country having avg(cost) > 150
```

Upgrade Steps as I went from a single core to Cloud based.

1. I installed 6.0 into a new directory.
2. I installed latest java 8
3. Added Java_home (set to java install dir)  and _Java_options
   (set to -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true) to windows env properties
4. I Changed the SolrConfig.xml to use  instead of the managed-schema
5. Updated schema.xml to my existing schema
6. Solr start -cloud
7. Solr create_collection -c MyCore-d C:\solr-6.0.0\server\solr\MyCore\conf -shards 1
8. Reindexed my data

Probably a better way, but thought I would share.